# Qt Installer Framework: How to add my program to Windows system variable PATH?

Tags: qt-installer

After my program installed I need installer to add program path to Windows system variable PATH. How to make this?

Installer must do this not me.

**UPD:**

And program path must be removed with uninstallation too.

**UPD2:**

Now I'm trying to do like this:

```
function Component()
{
    installer.installationFinished.connect(this, Component.prototype.installationFinishedPageIsShown);
    installer.uninstallationFinished.connect(this, Component.prototype.uninstallationFinishedPageIsShown);
}

Component.prototype.installationFinishedPageIsShown = function()
{
    try {
        if (installer.isInstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success) {
            installer.executeDetached("set", "PATH=%PATH%;@TargetDir@");
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

Component.prototype.uninstallationFinishedPageIsShown = function()
{
    try {
        if (installer.isUninstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success) {
            installer.executeDetached("set", "PATH=%PATH:;@TargetDir@=%");
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I just also struggled a lot with the arguments to the executeDetached function (OS X environment).

Because, apparently, characters are escaped when using a string 'inline'.
For me it worked by moving the arguments to a separate javascript variable, like:

```
var args = "PATH=%PATH:;@TargetDir@=%"
installer.executeDetached("set", args);
```

or even

```
var args = ["PATH=%PATH:;@TargetDir@=%"]
installer.executeDetached("set", args);
```

Did not validate, but hopefully it could point you, or others, in the right direction.

Also, wrapping the executeDetached in a console.log() helped me debugging a lot!

Answer (score -1):

From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
Choose Properties from the context menu.
Click the Advanced system settings link.
Click Environment Variables. ...
In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: This answer would be OK if this question was asked on SuperUser. The OP asks about a program they have written with an installer. That installer needs to do what your manual actions achieve. This is not an answer to the question

Comment: This answer would be OK if this question was asked without a mention of Qt Installer Framework. The question was asked about how to make installer do this itself.